# Should a clutch be immersed in oil prior to installation?

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, clutch, servicing

I heard somewhere that I should soak new friction plates in oil for at least two hours prior to installation.
Is this true? And if so, then why?

P.S.
I'm talking about a motorcycle's wet clutch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be; doing so thoroughly impregnates the surface with oil. If you simply assemble it dry, then oil will have a hard time getting to some of the friction plate surfaces so they'll run dry or nearly dry until the clutch has been used a number of times, and during that interval the clutch is likely to wear much faster than normal.

Comment: For how long? Some places say 15 minutes, some say overnight...

Comment: It can't hurt to immerse it for a longer time, but it could hurt to not immerse it long enough. Overnight would be a good cheap guarantee. BTW, don't use just **any** oil, use the exact same oil as the clutch will normally be exposed to.